# Streaming Videos Form Azure Blob Storage Unable To Seek and Extremely Slow

Tags: laravel, azure, video-streaming, html5-video, azure-blob-storage

I have uploaded some .mp4 files on Azure Blob storage. I am accessing the link to them on my website but the problem is that the video won't load/start for about 10-20 seconds (depending on how big the file is).

Also,
I am not able to seek the video. (jump ahead or back with the slider). This happens only when I use Azure blob storage( I am using chrome).

Does anyone have any suggestions as I could not find any answers but complains? Where should I look?

Thanks in advance!!

I have included  type="video/mp4"  in my HTML code

Comment: Can you show us you Html code ?  We don't know what problems you encountered and what you tried?

Comment: Hi @JasonPan, Thanks for answering! My html/vue worked fine before I switched to azure. After browsing all night, it seems that azure is trying to download the whole file before playing it. I need to change that to progressive loading. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using edge or other browsers to directly access the file address, such as `https://jaso***orage.blob.core.windows.net/media/b.mp4?sp=r&st=2021-02- 02T08:56:16Z&se=2021-02-02T16:***N521s0mJMYehA%3D` .

Comment: Because the problem I encountered before was that the browser played directly by default, and then I wanted to download the video file, so I looked for an Extension plug-in for the Chrome browser, and then encountered the situation you described now, I will proceed first download. So if there is a plug-in, it is recommended to disable it first.

Comment: Is [this gif](https://imgur.com/eJXwIn0) realistic the effect you want?

Comment: The gif is what I am trying to achieve. I tried it on edge with one of my videos like this: https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/media/1.mp4?sp=r&st=2021-02-%2002T08:56:16Z&se=2021-02-02T16:***N521s0mJMYehA%3D  I still coulnd't seek forward and it takes half a minute for the video to load.

Comment: Assuming that your video resources are very small, your problem should not appear, and it will not cause the unfriendly interaction phenomenon of waiting for 10s-20s to appear.

Comment: Hi Jason, your answer was very educational and helpful, thanks for that. However, the solution was to set the blob service properties rest API from azure. I was already using a plyr video player which was trying to convert videos in 206 Partial. Azure default version (x-ms-version is 2009) did not support the 206 partial content. Thanks.

Comment: @brpetrov Thanks for this. Helped me so much.

I would suggest adding your own answer to this with the information from your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set the Blob service properties rest API from Azure. I was already using a Plyr video player which was trying to convert videos in 206 Partial. Azure default version(x-ms-version is 2009) does not support the 206 partial content.

Thanks for the help!